# I want to make a folder where users can drop files but not delete them

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am working on a shared folder in windows 7. I want others to be able to drop files into this folder but not delete the files . Is this possible or is it just all or nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Right-click the folder, click properties, then Security tab. Click Advanced, Change Permissions, select the user/group you want to change, then Edit.

Be careful of setting deny permissions - you're better off just not allowing Delete. You can Google that for more information.

[image: screenshot of file permission settings]

Comment: Yep, thought this is how I would do it, guess I will have to talk to admin due to lack of privilege thank you